# How do I calculate the sensor size of a smartphone camera using the information in the exif metadata?

Tags: image, photo, photography

Just like the title says. I dont know too much about photography and cameras. I am just starting out.

I know that I can get the focal lenght, camera resolution and image resolution values but I don't know how to combine these to get the sensor size.